# Domain address- misunderstanding in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, web, dns

I don't understand why this Url:

```
 www.hortadascanas.com
```

and this Url:

`http://hortadascanas.com`

are not pointing to the same page. If you look the content, you can see that icons don't show up at the 2nd adress...Actually It seems to me that the 2nd Url links to an older version of the page.

I thought the "www" was a shortcut of "/public_html".

If I try with this address `http://hortadascanas.com/location` it is redirected to `http://www.hortadascanas.com/location` but the home page is not redirected.

What is happening ?

**EDIT**

This is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I guess I have to remove some lines because the site crashes if I add the lines you gave me....I have redirections loops...

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Should I delete this red line and recreate one pointing to the alias www.hortadascanas.com ?

Comment: do you find solution.??

Comment: No I have a error  with the redirection. "To many redirects". Ineed to delete some lines in my .htacces but dont know which ones.

Comment: Please check this, https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-CloudFlare-

Comment: It from your cloudflare settings

Comment: please check updated answer you will definitely find solution

Comment: Yeah you rock !! I was doing the redirecting from bluehost...but with cloudflare it works now. Good job . thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding the following lines at the beginning of the .htaccess file in your public_html folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hortadascanas.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hortadascanas.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

if you want to redirect both HTTP and HTTPS non-www Urls to www, you can combine rules as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For more information please read following :

https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_redirect_www_urls_to_nonwww/

**Edit**

In your case its because of CNAME in your cloudflare,please check complete guide for this,

https://help.ghost.org/hc/en-us/articles/223210747-Root-Domain-Setup-Using-CloudFlare

Comment: What can be done exactly ? What is the purpose of this code ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: this is use to redirect www to non-www url

Comment: I edit my request. Can you help with the .htaccess ?

Comment: Thank you very much for appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

`www.hortadascanas.com` and `hortadascanas.com` are simply different hostnames.

They don't have identical DNS resolution:

```
[ ~ ]
[ user ][ user@workstation.local ] %  host hortadascanas.com
hortadascanas.com has address 69.195.124.135
hortadascanas.com mail is handled by 0 mail.hortadascanas.com.
[ ~ ]
[ user ][ user@workstation.local ] %  host www.hortadascanas.com
www.hortadascanas.com has address 104.27.134.235
www.hortadascanas.com has address 104.27.135.235
www.hortadascanas.com has IPv6 address 2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:86eb
www.hortadascanas.com has IPv6 address 2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:87eb
```

You end up talking to two different computers depending on which hostname you use.

Running the IP addresses through `whois` we can see that `www.hortadascanas.com` is handled by Cloudflare, who provide a CDN and caching service.

> Actually It seems to me that the 2nd Url links to an older version of the page.

Presumably Cloudflare is loading the data from 69.195.124.135 and caching it … so it *is* an older version of the page.

---

Even if the two hostnames' DNS resolved to the same computer, you could still get different content. [Name based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) allows multiple websites to share a single IP address. The Hostname is included in the HTTP request header so the server can determine which site to return.

Comment: Your analysis seems right but what did I do wrong ? What am I supposed to do now ? Did I miss something with the nameservers in bluehost and cloudflare ?

Comment: I'd start by making sure everything worked on the real server, setting up `hortadascanas.com` to redirect to `www.hortadascanas.com` then telling Cloudflare to flush their cache and get fresh copies of everything from the real server.

Comment: Please have a look on my EDIT 2 .Thank you .

Comment: @PaulMartinez — No. You need an HTTP redirect. Having DNS say "www.hortadascanas.com is the same as www.hortadascanas.com" won't help! You want the server to go "You want hortadascanas.com? You can find it at www.hortadascanas.com" (or vice versa).

Comment: So I guess the first reply to this post was the good solution. Change the htaccess file and do a redirection to www.hortadascanas.com